# Tableview reload not accurate

Tags: ios, user-interface, refresh

I have a controller, that allows the user to type in a TextField.

Every time the user types a character, the string in that textfield is compared to an array of strings. If there is a match, the resulting array is displayed in a uitableview.

Here's the code:

```
 func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring:String){
       let SUBSSTRING = substring.uppercased()
        autocompleteStrings.removeAll()
        for thisSchool in schoolArray{
            if(thisSchool.name?.uppercased() .contains(SUBSSTRING))!{
                autocompleteStrings.append(thisSchool)
            }
        }
      autocompleteTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Basically, this works fine. **BUT!**

If the user types rather fast, the `autocompleteTableView` displays **one or more (empty) rows** than there actually are strings in the `autocompleteStrings` array.

I tried encapsulating the above code in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`, but that made things even *worse*.

I guess it has something to do with NeedsLayout or NeedsDisplay, but I've never really understood the mechanism behind it, and how/where to apply these.

I hope you can advise me

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
func searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring(substring: String) {
    let filtered = schoolArray.filter() { ($0.name ?? "").uppercased().range(of: substring.uppercased()) != nil }
    autocompleteStrings = filtered.map() { $0.name! }
    autocompleteTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: While your code is much cleaner (mine was a quick obj-c to Swift rework) the problem remains....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a lock?

1.in a async queue.

2.lock locks.

3.matching and array appending

4.lock unlocks.

5.reload in mainqueue